# Fastest way to generate random strings

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and functional programming. I'd like to create a list of 100,000 keys in the format: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX

I do something like this:

```
(defn get-key [chunk-size, key-length] 
 (apply str 
  (flatten
   (interpose "-" 
    (partition chunk-size 
     (take key-length 
      (repeatedly #(rand-nth "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))))))))

(defn dump-keys [n, chunk-size, key-length] 
 (with-open [wrt (io/writer "keys.txt")]
  (doseq [i (range n)]
   (.write wrt (str (get-key chunk-size key-length) "\n")))))
```

Which produces

```
KYFL0-7YO6J-30XMV-ZIGE7-MK009
MNQZH-K7L8I-35C0K-7DS7Q-OTZWI
MVB9D-GHME9-IMGCL-YPAKX-4YZVD
... etc
```

However, it takes around 5 seconds, which is comparatively long compared to a similar imperative-style algorithm.

What's considered an idiomatic (and quick) way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Is the time not dominated by the file I/O?

Comment: @A.Webb No, definitely the string generation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get maximum speed for this, I would suggest the following techniques:

- Construct the keys using a pre-allocated `(char-array 29)`
- Use `aset` to set the character at each position in the array
- Use [randomz](https://github.com/mikera/randomz) to get very fast random numbers (about 150% faster than `java.util.Random`)
- Look up the character with `.charAt`, e.g. something like `(.charAt "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" (int (Rand/r 36)))`
- Use `dotimes` for your loop - this is generally faster than mapping / anything with sequences

If you do all the above, you should get very efficient code, probably as fast as you could write it in pure Java.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. But I'm not sure how to integrate char-array and aset into the get-key function - do you mean to ditch the partition/interpose step and just set conditionally set the character vs a '-'?

Comment: Yeah, ditch the partition/interpose stuff altogether and do it in an imperative loop. Mutating primitive arrays is much faster than sequence operations. This is one of the situations where you can have either fast or idiomatic, but probably not both.

Comment: I've written an implementation of xoroshiro128+ in clojure that is the successor to the one used in randomz if you're interested

Answer (score 0):

If you want maximum performance, I don't think you'll do any better than writing this function in Java, and calling into it from Clojure. Or if you want to stay in Clojure, you can use `aset` to fill in Java `char` arrays, and use `(String. array)` to convert them to Strings. I don't think that's really "idiomatic" Clojure, but it will be fast.

Comment: This is a perfectly fast implementation of a fast RNG in clojure - https://github.com/thedavidmeister/xoroshiro128